# How do I save the layout of visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using Visual Studio Code but I have one problem with it.
I would like to always show the terminal below and never show "Open editors" in the explorer view. Now everytime I open a new folder I have to go to view -> Integrated terminal and hide the "Open Editors" tab in the explorer view.

I've already tried looking in the preferences but I can't find this, hopefully someone here knows a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add settings by going to File > Preferences and adding them in the right pane, in "User Settings" if you want to keep them for all workspaces or in "Workspace Settings" for this workspace only.

To remove the "Open Editors" list, you can put

```
{
    "explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,
}
```

I couldn't find the setting to show the terminal though..

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this worked :)  too bad vscode doesn't have an option for the terminal as well, maby it'd be possible to run the command to create a terminal view when a specific event of vscode fires like opening a folder

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut key to open the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code is by pressing `Ctrl + ~ key`. It open the terminal on the current working directory.

**To hide Open editors pane**

1. Go to Files -> Preferences -> Settings
2. The *settings.json* should open up
3. Search for `explorer.openEditors.visible`, set its value to 0 to hide the pane